# UILabel is not showing in neither in simulator or iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

So i am showing a model controller on top of a view controller. And i have texts in the model controller, but somehow the texts are not visible. I tried everything but somehow labels are not visible. But of you stay on the page for like 30 -40 sec the text shows up. Also this model controller is called from main view controller after a successful service(REST) call. If i call the model without making the service call then labels are visible in simulator/iPad both. But if i call it after service call inside success block then labels are not visible. I tried adding the text programmatically but still same issue. I tried debugging using Color blended layers, but the label is not at all visible in the view somehow. :(

```
  [self.serviceManager getCustDetails:account successBlock:^(NSDictionary * successDict) {
     [self hideLoadingAnimation];
     NSDictionary *custData = [[successDict objectForKey:@"txnData"] objectForKey:@"custData"];

     self.showCurrYear = [iraContribData objectForKey:@"showCurrYear"];

     if ([self.showCurrYear  isEqual: @"true"]){
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CSegue" sender:self];
     }

     } failureBlock:^(NSDictionary * failureDict) {
        [self hideLoadingAnimation];
        NSLog(@"Failiure Dict %@",failureDict);
     }];
```

And this prepareForSegue method, -

```
  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
     {
        if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CSegue"]) {
            CustViewController *cVC = segue.destinationViewController;
            cVC.delegate = self;
            [cVC setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
            cVC.preferredContentSize =  CGSizeMake(800,750);
        }
     }
```

Below is my screen in storyboard, but in simulator the label is not visible, only continue and close button is visible.

[image]

Please help!, any suggestions are most welcome. Thanks!

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in your success block, is it being hit immediately? Or only after those 30-40 seconds?

Comment: It is hit immediately, and model comes up but labels are not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the delay is due to a user interface update not made on the main thread.

Try to make sure that your code is executed on the main thread using `dispatch_async` like this :

```
[self.serviceManager getCustDetails:account successBlock:^(NSDictionary * successDict) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self hideLoadingAnimation];
        NSDictionary *custData = [[successDict objectForKey:@"txnData"] objectForKey:@"custData"];

        self.showCurrYear = [iraContribData objectForKey:@"showCurrYear"];

        if ([self.showCurrYear isEqualToString:@"true"]){
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CSegue" sender:self];
        }
    });
} failureBlock:^(NSDictionary * failureDict) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self hideLoadingAnimation];
        NSLog(@"Failiure Dict %@",failureDict);
    });
}];
```

Comment: Thats it, You are awesome!!!! ,BIG THANK YOU. I wasted my whole day on this. Thank You soooo much.